# Disable progress bar during Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, installation, qemu

The screenshot below is the Ubuntu 18.04 installer as seen via `virsh console` / tty0 i.e. the installation takes place on a remote system in a guest VM.

Is it anyhow possible to see installer's activity details happening in background?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to watch the output on tty4.

[image]

Switch to tty4 with `alt`+`f4`

[image]

Here are some tips on switching the tty with qemu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54814/how-can-i-ctrl-alt-f-to-get-to-a-tty-in-a-qemu-session

Using `alt` + left/right arrows seems like the most promising approach.

Comment: Scheider - that is, if you access the guest via VMWare UI. What if you have just a bash login?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Alt-F4 -> closes my bash/ssh terminal window.

Comment: Well, I can't do any more tests until tomorrow. Until then you could google how to switch virtual console with qemu. I'm sure it's documented.

Comment: The OP is using a (virtual) serial console, not a framebuffer console. This won't work at all.